# EventHandler with React Routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a nested route in react with react-router plugin and want to connect the ui with some functionality

```
class MyLogin extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={
  email:'',
  password:''
}
}
  login() {
    alert("OK");
  }
}
```

and the ui

```
const Login = ({ match }) => {
    return (
       ...
       <TextField
          hintText="Email eingeben"
          type="email"
          floatingLabelText="Email"
          onChange = {(event,newValue) => 
             MyLogin.setState({email:newValue})}
          />
       ...
       <RaisedButton label="Anmelden" primary={true} /*style={style}*/ onClick={ MyLogin.login }/>
       ...
```

So how can i get access to state variables and bind the event handler from the button to my own code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to access another component inside a component you can use `ref` for that. But `refs` shouldn't be overused. I provide this example only for educational purposes (you should probably rework your app to follow good patterns).

```js
class MyLogin extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
  }
  login() {
    alert("OK");
  }
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

const Login = ({ match, MyLoginRef }) => {
  if (!MyLoginRef) return null;
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="email"
        onChange={event =>
          MyLoginRef.setState({ email: event.currentTarget.value })
        }
      />
      <button label="Anmelden" onClick={MyLoginRef.login} />
    </>
  );
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {}
  refFn = (el) => (this.setState({el}))
  render() {
    console.log(this.el);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <MyLogin ref={this.refFn}/>
        <Login MyLoginRef={this.state.el} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

live demo on codesandbox.io https://codesandbox.io/s/kmv6x4j237